# Undefined variable: _SESSION in the redirected PHP file

Tags: php, session

I am quite new to PHP. I am trying to write a login script in PHP. My index.html file takes the username and password and submits the form to login.php. This login.php file checks if the user is registered and creates a session if so. After that it redirects to the file controlpanel.php

My problem is I get proper values on reading the session variable in login.php(just before redirecting to controlpanel.php). However in controlpanel.php, when I try to read the session variable it gives the error:

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in D:\Work\Projects\phpapp\myecom\admin\controlpanel.php on line 2

My code:

login.php

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION)){ob_start(); session_start(); }else{error_log("Session already set");}
require_once("../config/config.php");
?>

<?php   
  require_once("../classes/autoload.php");
  $objUser = new User();

    if (isset($_POST["username"])){
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $pass = $_POST["password"]; 

        error_log("about to check for registration");

        if($objUser->isRegisteredUser($username, $pass, 2)){
            error_log("user registered");

            Login::loginUser($objUser->id, 2);

            error_log("session id in login.php: " . $_SESSION["uId"]);

            header("Location:controlpanel.php");   
          }
        else{
            error_log("not registered");
          //redirect to the registration page
        }


    }


?>
```

controlpanel.php

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    error_log("session not set");
}else{
    error_log("session set in controlpanel: " . $_SESSION["uId"]);
}

?>
```

PHP error_log:

> [25-Oct-2014 18:08:51 Europe/Paris] about to check for registration
>
> [25-Oct-2014 18:08:51 Europe/Paris] user registered
>
> [25-Oct-2014 18:08:51 Europe/Paris] session id in login.php: 1
>
> [25-Oct-2014 18:08:51 Europe/Paris] session not set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't start the session in your `controlpanel.php` script.

Always call `session_start();` before using `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...

Surprisingly it was working without adding session_start() in controlpanel.php a few days ago.

Is there any way it would work without writing the session_start() in  the controlpanel.php? Was anything happening because of a saved cokie that expired or got deleted now. Just trying to understand how did it work before and trying to recall what changes I made...

Comment: I don't see how it would have worked without starting the session... PHP is not going to give the thread access to the `$_SESSION`'s data without first calling `session_start()`; that is when it is going to match the id of the cookie sent during the request to the information stored in the PHP session database. One reason why it could have been working might be that you were importing a script that called `session_start()`. Anyhow, I suggest you check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php for more information about how sessions work :)